# android media player streaming issue

Tags: android-mediaplayer

sorry for my english my problem is in my app media player plays streaming urls. if user clicks next button immediateley then ui blocks for some time and giving ANR problem If it is working on GPRS how to resolve that issue Please some body help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the UI thread does not get any response within 5 seconds from your action, it will hang and will show you ANR. So, do one thing: whenever user clicks on the button, start a progress loader (spinner) and as soon as you get response from your action, dismiss the progress dialog and show the result.